# How to avoid that a Button with longPressListener also triggers the normal Command on longPress?

Tags: codenameone

I have a `Button` which I want to have one behavior when pressed normally (launch a `Command`) and another when longPressed (using a `longPressListener`). However, when longPressing the `Button`, it also runs the 'normalPress' `Command`. How can I ensure that *only* the longPressListener is called on the longPress?

Answer (score 1):

There's no builtin support for this. This is something your business logic will have to deal with manually. The core reason for this is that we have no way of knowing at that stage that the long press processed the action.

```
 private boolean longPressHandled;

 void callbackFromLongPress() {
      longPressHandled = true;
      // rest of your logic...
 }

 void actionEventCallback() {
      if(longPressHandled) {
          longPressHandled = false;
          return;
      }
      // rest of your logic...
 }
```